# Unable to connect or query redis cluster

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, redis-cluster

I am currently trying to create a redis-cluster. Below I have given the commands, the contents of docker-compose and the results. As you can see there are no errors. The cluster is built, no errors. But as soon as I want to execute this code, it returns nothing, not even an error. There is no response. I don't quite understand what is wrong with the docker compose redis cluster configuration. Maybe I've got the addresses wrong somehow

```golang
func main() {
    clusterClient := redis.NewClusterClient(&redis.ClusterOptions{
        Addrs: []string{
            "172.18.0.2:6379",
            "172.18.0.3:6380",
            "172.18.0.4:6381",
        },
    })

    var ctx = context.Background()
    err := clusterClient.ForEachShard(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, shard *redis.Client) error {
        return shard.Ping(ctx).Err()
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Sprintf("FAILED CREATE REDIS CLUSTER CONNECTION: %s", err)
        return
    }

    //send SET command
    err = clusterClient.Set(ctx, "data1341241414", "bar", 1*time.Hour).Err()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Sprintf("FAILED SET DATA: %s", err)
        return
    }

    //send GET command and print the value
    val, err := clusterClient.Get(ctx, "data1341241414").Result()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if val == "" {
        fmt.Sprintf("EMPTY DATA")
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("foo ", val)
}
```

Or, the execution is intentionally frozen and cannot be completed with any result whatsoever

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  redis1:
    image: redis:latest
    networks:
      redis-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.2
    ports:
      - "6379"
    command: "redis-server --port 6379 --cluster-enabled yes --cluster-config-file nodes.conf --cluster-node-timeout 5000 --appendonly yes"
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis1:/data

  redis2:
    image: redis:latest
    networks:
      redis-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.3
    ports:
      - "6380"
    command: "redis-server --port 6380 --cluster-enabled yes --cluster-config-file nodes.conf --cluster-node-timeout 5000 --appendonly yes"
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis2:/data

  redis3:
    image: redis:latest
    networks:
      redis-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.4
    ports:
      - "6381"
    command: "redis-server --port 6381 --cluster-enabled yes --cluster-config-file nodes.conf --cluster-node-timeout 5000 --appendonly yes"
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis3:/data

networks:
  redis-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.0.0/16
```

Create cluster command

```
docker exec -it <redis1-container-id> redis-cli --cluster create \
  172.18.0.2:6379 172.18.0.3:6380 172.18.0.4:6381 \
  --cluster-replicas 0
```

output

```
>>> Performing hash slots allocation on 3 nodes...
Master[0] -> Slots 0 - 5460
Master[1] -> Slots 5461 - 10922
Master[2] -> Slots 10923 - 16383
M: 36eb4929ea55131aff4b9eaf62ac99b0a0d873c3 172.18.0.2:6379
   slots:[0-5460] (5461 slots) master
M: 0c54336ac7f68bb8e3b112975ad3714c545bc693 172.18.0.3:6380
   slots:[5461-10922] (5462 slots) master
M: c879dba5ffe0244c4b669e7ab41eb1eccba0036d 172.18.0.4:6381
   slots:[10923-16383] (5461 slots) master
Can I set the above configuration? (type 'yes' to accept): yes
>>> Nodes configuration updated
>>> Assign a different config epoch to each node
>>> Sending CLUSTER MEET messages to join the cluster
Waiting for the cluster to join
..
>>> Performing Cluster Check (using node 172.18.0.2:6379)
M: 36eb4929ea55131aff4b9eaf62ac99b0a0d873c3 172.18.0.2:6379
   slots:[0-5460] (5461 slots) master
M: 0c54336ac7f68bb8e3b112975ad3714c545bc693 172.18.0.3:6380
   slots:[5461-10922] (5462 slots) master
M: c879dba5ffe0244c4b669e7ab41eb1eccba0036d 172.18.0.4:6381
   slots:[10923-16383] (5461 slots) master
[OK] All nodes agree about slots configuration.
>>> Check for open slots...
>>> Check slots coverage...
[OK] All 16384 slots covered.
```

redis cluster info output

```
cluster info
cluster_state:ok
cluster_slots_assigned:16384
cluster_slots_ok:16384
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:0
cluster_known_nodes:3
cluster_size:3
cluster_current_epoch:3
cluster_my_epoch:1
cluster_stats_messages_ping_sent:33
cluster_stats_messages_pong_sent:34
cluster_stats_messages_sent:67
cluster_stats_messages_ping_received:32
cluster_stats_messages_pong_received:33
cluster_stats_messages_meet_received:2
cluster_stats_messages_received:67
total_cluster_links_buffer_limit_exceeded:0
```